# Is there an easy way to buffer io.ReaderAt and io.WriterAt?

Tags: go

I'm implementing a custom sftp server for a project at work that will use an AWS compatible system as the backend. Based on what I am seeing, I'm thinking I should implement the [sftp.Handlers](http://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/sftp#Handlers) interface using the [s3.Uploader and s3.Downloader](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/) or [s3.PutObject and s3.GetObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/).

I've used [io.PipeReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#PipeReader) and [io.PipeWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#PipeWriter) before to pipe an io.Writer to an io.Reader but in this case, I need to do something like:

- Get: io.ReaderAt <- ??? <- io.Reader
- Put: io.WriterAt -> ??? -> io.Reader

I'm guessing ??? will be different in both cases but they both seem like they'd be a type of pipe where we hold data until it's available for the other end. Does something like this exist or do I need to implement it myself? Any suggestions on implementing it?

Comment: Why would you need to expose the s3 SDK as an *sftp* handler? What would the "something" you feel you need actually *do*?

Comment: Bascially, because the business says so. I'm retrofitting an existing system. The clients expect to use SFTP and we can't change that. Other parts of the project are using an S3 clone and the business wants the submissions to now be stored there.

Comment: As to what it would actual do, is still a mystery. Thus the question. I'm guessing in the Get example it would read from the io.Reader filling a buffer. It would then wait on the ReadAt() calls until the buffer had the data available to get it.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a good solution?

Comment: No good solution. I ended up saving the incoming file to disk before uploading it to s3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm personally making use of https://github.com/avvmoto/buf-readerat which specifically buffers ReadAt. Saved me a lot of pain.